# Rows is null when joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

I have the following sql statement:

```
                SELECT 
                    i.ITEM_NO,
                    i.HFB_NO,
                    t.IMAGE_PE_NO
                FROM cpc.item_t i  LEFT OUTER JOIN  cpc.ITEM_IMAGE_T b ON i.ITEM_NO=b.ITEM_NO LEFT  OUTER JOIN  IMAGE_T t ON b.IMAGE_NO=t.IMAGE_NO WHERE i.ITEM_STATE IN ('Saleable','Approved')
                    AND(i.COMCLASS_NAME != 'UTG' OR i.COMCLASS_NAME IS NULL)
                    AND i.ITEM_TYPE IN('ART','SPR')
                    AND i.ITEM_NO='09252748'
                    AND b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet'
                    AND t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3'
                ORDER BY HFB_NO, PA_NO, PROD_NAME
```

The result from the above sql Is 0 rows.

This Is wrong, because I want the SQL to return all the data from `item_t i`, even If the item does not exist in `ITEM_IMAGE_T b`. Thats why I have a Left Join there.

However, If I remove `AND b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet'` and `AND t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3'`, It works. The data is returned as expected.

So, my question: How can I apply `AND b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet'` and `AND t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3'` when the Item is found in `ITEM_IMAGE_T b`, and not apply them when It's not found?

EDIT:

I have added a new JOIN: `LEFT OUTER JOIN cpc.item_cty_spec_t f ON i.ITEM_NO=f.ITEM_NO`

So the whole query Is now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                            i.HFB_NO,
                            i.PA_NO,
                            t.IMAGE_PE_NO,
                            f.ITEM_NO as CTY_ITEM_NO
                        FROM cpc.item_t i
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN cpc.ITEM_IMAGE_T b ON (i.ITEM_NO = b.ITEM_NO AND b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet')
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN IMAGE_T t ON (b.IMAGE_NO = t.IMAGE_NO AND  t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3')
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN cpc.item_cty_spec_t f ON i.ITEM_NO=f.ITEM_NO 
                        WHERE
                            i.ITEM_STATE IN ('Saleable', 'Approved')
                            AND (i.COMCLASS_NAME != 'UTG' OR i.COMCLASS_NAME IS NULL)
                            AND i.ITEM_TYPE IN ('ART', 'SPR')
                            AND i.ITEM_NO = '00051570'
                        ORDER BY HFB_NO, PA_NO, PROD_NAME
```

Now I have the same problem here. If the item does not exist in `cpc.item_cty_spec_t` it should still return the rows from `item_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Such cases keep the outer joined table column filters in `ON` Clause of outer JOIN instead of `WHERE` clause.

Try This code:

```
SELECT i.ITEM_NO, i.HFB_NO, t.IMAGE_PE_NO
    FROM cpc.item_t i
         LEFT OUTER JOIN cpc.ITEM_IMAGE_T b ON (i.ITEM_NO = b.ITEM_NO AND b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet')
         LEFT OUTER JOIN IMAGE_T t ON (b.IMAGE_NO = t.IMAGE_NO AND t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3')
   WHERE     i.ITEM_STATE IN ('Saleable', 'Approved')
         AND (i.COMCLASS_NAME != 'UTG' OR i.COMCLASS_NAME IS NULL)
         AND i.ITEM_TYPE IN ('ART', 'SPR')
         AND i.ITEM_NO = '09252748'
ORDER BY HFB_NO, PA_NO, PROD_NAME
```

Comment: Isnt it returning the row now? It should return a row with CITY_ITEM_NO as NULL if any item doesn't exist in cpc.item_cty_spec_t

Comment: The Item numbers are different in first and second query. Can you please check the other conditions satisfies for item_no '00051570' ?

Comment: @BikasRanjanBhoi: 00051570 exists in item_t but noi in item_cty_spec_t. 09252748 exists in both.

Comment: @Bryan That's fine. for this new item do these conditions satisfy?

`i.ITEM_STATE IN ('Saleable', 'Approved')
                            AND (i.COMCLASS_NAME != 'UTG' OR i.COMCLASS_NAME IS NULL)
                            AND i.ITEM_TYPE IN ('ART', 'SPR')`

Comment: Hope you got your answer. You need to revisit the requirement now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bring the data if IMAGE_USAGE is "Internet" AND IMAGE_SIZE is "S3". But if doesn't exists in the join, you want it too, right? Any other value in usage or size should be ignored.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    i.ITEM_NO, i.HFB_NO,
    t.IMAGE_PE_NO
FROM
    cpc.item_t i
LEFT OUTER JOIN cpc.ITEM_IMAGE_T b ON i.ITEM_NO=b.ITEM_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN IMAGE_T t ON b.IMAGE_NO=t.IMAGE_NO
WHERE
    i.ITEM_STATE IN ('Saleable','Approved')
    AND(i.COMCLASS_NAME != 'UTG' OR i.COMCLASS_NAME IS NULL)
    AND i.ITEM_TYPE IN('ART','SPR')
    AND i.ITEM_NO='09252748'
    AND ((b.IMAGE_USAGE = 'Internet' AND t.IMAGE_SIZE = 'S3') OR (b.IMAGE_USAGE is null AND t.IMAGE_SIZE is null))
ORDER BY HFB_NO, PA_NO, PROD_NAME
```